# Chrome Mobile Android [Add to Homescreen]

Tags: android, html5, google-chrome

Hoje descobri que consigo fazer uma página como um APP nativo, com atalho na homescreen, abre quase em tela cheia... Fiz um teste e funcionou, agora preciso fazer com que funcione 100% fullscreen, escondendo a barra de cima e de baixo, no Android 4.3  e  4.4, será que é possível?

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen?hl=pt-br

Comment: Ronny, você pode adicionar um screenshot de como sua aplicação está atualmente e o que você gostaria de ver removido?

Comment: Então Onilton, fiz 3 screenshot's em uma unica imagem, veja como fica no "screen 1", ele é um "APP da Web" como mostra no "screen 2", esse "screen 3" e como eu gostaria que ficasse, "screen 3" é uma pagina normal no Chrome, fiz e coloquei um botão de fullscreen do HTML5. Quatro link's abaixo, da imagem, da página com fullscreen HTML5, da página que fiz que ta no "APP da Web" e a página onde mostra o "Add to Homescreen" official.

http://goo.gl/p8a7Um
http://goo.gl/qP7OOR
http://goo.gl/IoCk39
http://goo.gl/LercYp

Espero ter sido claro... Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com "esconder a barra de cima e de baixo" você se refere [as barras do sistema](https://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html#system-bars), correto?

A única forma de remover elas no Chrome para Android foram *vídeos*: [tentei testar se é possível](http://jsbin.com/waxon/1) usar isso em um site mas após testar vi que nenhum navegador suporta o codec. A menos que alguém crie outro codec essa ideia não pode ser usada.

Outra solução é *usar o Firefox para Android* e baixar a extensão ["full screen"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/full-screen-252573/?src=hp-dl-featured): essa extensão permite que você esconda as barras do sistema.

Ainda há uma terceira opção: usar o [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) junto com [a configuração de tela cheia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680323/1850091) do Android.

Comment: Então @GustavoRodrigues, a ideia é retirar as barras mesmo... Da forma que esta, ta legal (App Web), quem sabe nas próximas atualizações do Chrome eles colocam realmente fullscreen, já que o Android 4.4.x veio com uma nova feature fullscreen. Não testei em nenhum iOS ainda, futuramente faço testes! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Deve haver alguma solução parecida com a que encontramos hoje para os dispositivos com iOS.
No iOS, basta que eu adicione o código abaixo para que, ao abrir o aplicativo através da homescreen, ele abra em fullscreen.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```